# Parsing data using XDocument yield no result -Why?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file as under

```
<!--Sample Person Data-->
<Person>
  <PersonDetail PersonId="1">
    <Name>Priyanka Das</Name>
    <Age>30</Age>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <LivesIn>Bangalore</LivesIn>
    <Email>nb@training.com</Email>
  </PersonDetail>
  <PersonDetail PersonId="2">
    <Name>Shashidhar Nikatani</Name>
    <Age>40</Age>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <LivesIn>Bangalore</LivesIn>
    <Email>sn@training.com</Email>
  </PersonDetail>
  <PersonDetail PersonId="3">
    <Name>Arundhuti Roy</Name>
    <Age>27</Age>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <LivesIn>Kerala</LivesIn>
    <Email>ab@training.com</Email>
  </PersonDetail>
  <PersonDetail PersonId="4">
    <Name>Nitin Mallik</Name>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <LivesIn>Bangalore</LivesIn>
    <Email>ng@training.com</Email>
  </PersonDetail>
  <PersonDetail PersonId="5">
    <Name>Essaki Raja Kandaswamy</Name>
    <Age>27</Age>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <LivesIn>Madras</LivesIn>
    <Email>er@training.com</Email>
  </PersonDetail>
</Person>
```

I need to find out the details of Persons who Lives In Bangalore.

I have done the below but not able to get any result

```
 XDocument xmlSource = null;
   xmlSource = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Personsample.xml");

            var query = from data in xmlSource.Descendants("Person")
                        where (string)data.Element("LivesIn") == "Bangalore"
                        select data;
```

Help needed

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from data in xmlSource.Descendants("PersonDetail")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no direct "LivesIn" children of "Person", so `data.Element("LivesIn")` will invariably not yield anything.

Are you sure you didn't mean:

```
from data in xmlSource.Descendants("PersonDetail")
                    where (string)data.Element("LivesIn") == "Bangalore"
                    select data;
```